# Binary Search Algorithm in JavaScript Max Call Stack Size Exceeded

Tags: javascript, recursion, binary-search

Thanks for checking out my question. I'm trying to implement the binary search algorithm on a recursive function that will operate on sorted arrays. When I run the code below, I get the maximum call stack size exceeded error. I would assume that means that my base case is not catching, but maybe I'm just not seeing it.

```
var binarySearch = function(array, target, min, max) {

    min = min || 0;
    max = max || array.length - 1;

    if(min<=max){
      mid = Math.floor((min+max)/2);

      if(array[mid] === target){
        return mid;
      }
      else{
        if(array[mid]<target){
          min = mid-1; 
        }
        else{
          max = mid+1;
        }
      }
      return binarySearch(array,target,min,max);
    }
    return null;
};
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve with `max = max || array.length - 1`? Why are you using a boolean operator on integers?

Comment: isn't `[].indexOf()` a lot faster/simpler/better? in general, console.log can demystify such things.

Comment: Are you sure min or max changes each time you call the function?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Sure. The min and max parameters are not necessarily provided on function call, so the max becomes either a recursively provided max, or a default value of array.length-1.

Comment: @dandavis I would normally use indexOf as you suggested! This is a personal learning exercise. And I'm not totally sure if indexOf is *always* better for all cases. I was under the impression that very large data sets benefitted from the binary search algorithm.

Comment: @Trevor I see. Have you considered adding parentheses since you are using this trick for setting default values? `max || (array.length -1 )`

Comment: It works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/kkukvgp6/ Could you show some example input that causes the problem?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/LLxsnHrn3MuL5EUBUAFh?p=preview
- example with stack overflow.

Comment: @DmitriyKhudorozhkov That's not a sorted array. The OP specifically says that the function operates on sorted arrays (although it's very possible that he has an unsorted array too.)

Comment: the problem is it floors the (min+max)/2, it can continuously return the same thing

Comment: @Juhana yeah, got it. Actually, the code may be correct - it's just the input validation that's missing. I found that function works correctly with correct input data.

Comment: @Juhana binarySearch([1,2,3,4],4)

Comment: @Derek this is just short circuiting, a common operation in Javascript

Answer (score 0):

Just a small logic bug. If the current element `array[mid]` is lower than `target`, then `mid` must be increased, not decreased (and vice versa):

```
var binarySearch = function(array, target, min, max) {

    min = min || 0;
    max = max || array.length - 1;

    if(min<=max){
      mid = Math.floor((min+max)/2);

      if(array[mid] === target){
        return mid;
      }
      else{
        if(array[mid]<target){
          min = mid+1; 
        }
        else{
          max = mid-1;
        }
      }
      return binarySearch(array,target,min,max);
    }
    return null;
};

binarySearch([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],6); // 6
```